# Internet Explorer 11 / Outlook 2013 single sign-on anomaly: it keeps sending Authorization: headers

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-explorer, ntlm, single-sign-on

I have IE 11 and Outlook 2013 on the client side. On ther server side there's centos7, apache 2.4 with auth_ntlm_winbind_module and winbindd. The server URI (http://server.yourdomain.com) is added to the "Local sites" in Explorer's Options / Security.

Apache is configured to use/ask authentication for a single URI (/sso.php) with a .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule auth_ntlm_winbind_module>
  <FilesMatch "sso.php$">
    AuthName "NTLM authentication"
    NTLMAuth on
    NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
    NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
    AuthType NTLM
    require valid-user
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that when IE or Outlook are configured to use SSO, they occasionally and randomly (based on my observation by a 1:10-20 ratio) send the ntlm authorization data with http requests not just to /sso.php, rather to any other URIs as well.

The ngrep output for a problematic http query:

```
T 1.2.3.4:49229 -> 1.2.3.5:80 [AP]
POST /message.php HTTP/1.1..Accept: */*..Content-Type: app
lication/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8..X-Roundcube
-Request: undefined..X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest..Ref
erer: search.php..Accept-Language:
hu,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3..Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate..U
ser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6
.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; Microsoft Outl
ook 15.0.4420)..Host: SERVER..Content-Length: 0..
Connection: Keep-Alive..Cache-Control: no-cache..Cookie: s
plitter2=421; PHPSESSID=38jo8vdmvvfotqhivffsocgif3..Author
ization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG
A4AlAAAADw==....
#
T 1.2.3.5:80 -> 1.2.3.4:49229 [AP]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Mon, 15 Sep 2014 08:52:50 GMT..Serv
er: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16..X-Powered-By: PHP/5.
4.16..Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT..Cache-Contro
l: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
check=0..Pragma: no-cache..Content-Length: 42..Keep-Alive:
timeout=5, max=100..Connection: Keep-Alive..Content-Type:
text/html; charset=UTF-8.....invalid id:
#
T 1.2.3.4:49229 -> 1.2.3.5:80 [A]
```

The trouble is that when they do so, then they fail to send the POST parameters
with the http request, and the website scripts return error messages. However 
when trying again immediately, then it seems that it works properly:

No 'Authorization:' header, and proper POST data sent to the webserver.

A valid post query should like like this (notice the absense of the Authorization:
header, and the presence of the 'id' field):

```
T 1.2.3.4:49229 -> 1.2.3.5:80 [AP]
POST /message.php HTTP/1.1..Accept: */*..Content-Type: app
lication/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8..X-Roundcube
-Request: undefined..X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest..Ref
erer: search.php..Accept-Language:
hu,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3..Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate..U
ser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6
.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; Microsoft Outl
ook 15.0.4420)..Host: SZERVER..Content-Length: 15.
.Connection: Keep-Alive..Cache-Control: no-cache..Cookie:
splitter2=421; PHPSESSID=38jo8vdmvvfotqhivffsocgif3....
#
T 1.2.3.4:49229 -> 1.2.3.5:80 [AP]
id=4992&search=
```

So the question is how to prevent IE 11 or Outlook 2013 to send the ntlm authorization credentials to any URIs in every 10-20 seconds where apache actually doesn't ask for it? Or how to force IE or Outlook to do send the POST data even if they send ntlm authorization data to the webserver?

Thanks for any hints or clues.

Comment: I vaguely recall that HTTP NTLM auth is per-connection (unlike all other mechanisms which are per-request)... Out of curiosity, why are you using NTLM in 2014 instead of [Kerberos](http://blogs.technet.com/b/authentication/archive/2006/04/07/ntlm-s-time-has-passed.aspx)?

Comment: Because the found apache module (auth_ntlm_winbind) supports that (on Linux). If you are aware of a better solution, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Either [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/modauthgssapi/mod_auth_gssapi) from the FreeIPA project, or the older [mod_auth_kerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/), should support it.